# Regular expression to allow characters and numeric but not special charecters

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I am using this expression..

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_]*(?<!_)$
```

It is not allowing me to provide numbers . when i change to

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_][0-9]*(?<!_)$
```

it is still not allowing me to enter numbers.. An y help on wht i missing here. Ia am developing this in c#

Comment: Can you list the requirement in words. Do your string need to start with alphabets? Can't it end with `_`. Write out these conditions.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a few example strings.

Answer (score 0):

The text between the square brackets is called a "[character class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx)". A character class will match one of the characters encoded within.

If you want to added support for numbers, you need to add them to the character class, not add *another* character class:

```
[a-zA-Z_0-9]
```

You current expression:

```
[a-zA-Z_][0-9]*
```

will match a lowercase letter, an uppercase letter or an underscore followed by 0 or more numbers.